# C# Returning a pointer created with stackalloc inside a function

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe, stackalloc

I have C# code that interacts with C++ code, which performs operations with strings.

I have this piece of code in a static helper class:

```
internal static unsafe byte* GetConstNullTerminated(string text, Encoding encoding)
{
    int charCount = text.Length;
    fixed (char* chars = text)
    {
        int byteCount = encoding.GetByteCount(chars, charCount);
        byte* bytes = stackalloc byte[byteCount + 1];
        encoding.GetBytes(chars, charCount, bytes, byteCount);
        *(bytes + byteCount) = 0;
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it returns a pointer to the bytes created with the `stackalloc` keyword.
However from the C# Specifications 18.8:

> All stack allocated memory blocks created during the execution of a function member are automatically discarded when that function member returns.

Does it mean that the pointer is actually invalid as soon as the method returns?

Current usage of the method:

```
byte* bytes = StringHelper.GetConstNullTerminated(value ?? string.Empty, Encoding);
DirectFunction(NativeMethods.SCI_SETTEXT, UIntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr) bytes);
```

Should the code be changed to

```
...
int byteCount = encoding.GetByteCount(chars, charCount);
byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteCount + 1];
fixed (byte* bytes = byteArray)
{
    encoding.GetBytes(chars, charCount, bytes, byteCount);
    *(bytes + byteCount) = 0;
}
return byteArray;
```

And use `fixed` again on the array returned, to pass the pointer to the `DirectFunction` method?

I'm trying to minimise the number of `fixed` usages (including the `fixed` statements in other overloads of `GetByteCount()` and `GetBytes()` of `Encoding`).

tl;dr

1. Is the pointer invalid as soon as the method returns? Is it invalid at the point of being passed to `DirectFunction()`?
2. If so, what is the best way to use the fewest `fixed` statements to achieve the task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it mean that the pointer is actually invalid as soon as the method returns?

Yes, it is technically invalid - although it almost certainly won't be detected. This scenario is self-inflicted via `unsafe`.  Any action on that memory now has undefined behavior. Anything you do, but in particular calling methods, may randomly overwrite that memory - *or not* - depending on the relative stack-frame sizes and depth.

This scenario is specifically one of the ones that the proposed future `ref` changes hope to target, meaning: allowing `stackalloc` into `ref` (rather than a pointer), with the compiler knowing that it is a stack-referring `ref` or ref-like type, and thus disallowing `ref`-return of that value.

Ultimately, the moment you type `unsafe` you're saying "I take full responsibility if this goes wrong". In this case, it is indeed wrong.

---

It *is* valid to use the pointer *before* leaving the method, so one viable approach might be (assuming yo want a fairly general purpose API) to allow the caller to pass in a delegate or interface that specifies what the caller wants you to *do* with the pointer, i.e.

```
StringHelper.GetConstNullTerminated(value ?? string.Empty, Encoding,
    ptr => DirectFunction(NativeMethods.SCI_SETTEXT, UIntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr) ptr));
```

with:

```
unsafe delegate void PointerAction(byte* ptr);
internal static unsafe void GetConstNullTerminated(string text, Encoding encoding,
    PointerAction action)
{
    int charCount = text.Length;
    fixed (char* chars = text)
    {
        int byteCount = encoding.GetByteCount(chars, charCount);
        byte* bytes = stackalloc byte[byteCount + 1];
        encoding.GetBytes(chars, charCount, bytes, byteCount);
        *(bytes + byteCount) = 0;
        action(bytes);
    }
}
```

Note also that very large strings may cause you to stack-overflow.

Comment: Never thought about passing a delegate. This solution would be as fast as manually copy-paste-inlining `GetConstNullTerminated` into the destinations, if there is no performance downside of using delegates. I'll have to do some research on delegate performances now...

Comment: @A.A.Ron delegate performance will be completely immeasurable compared to the encoding work and the double-walk of the input string (once for length, once for encode)

Comment: Will delegates actually improve performance over just allocating on the heap? A delegate still requires heap allocation. Depending on the size of strings being passed, you could easily end up allocating more memory to hold the delegate than the actual string.

Comment: @Jarra the lambda shown doesn't capture any variables, and as such is actually backed by a static field that stores a reused delegate instance, so there is no ongoing allocation cost after the first call. In the more general case, a delegate instance is not large - conceptually just a target instance and a method pointer - essentially 16 bytes on x64 (plus the object header, plus some other overheads) - not expensive, but of course zero alloc (as shown) is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

stackalloc causes memory to be allocated on the stack. The stack is automatically unwound when the function returns. C# is protecting you from creating a hanging pointer by not letting you return the pointer, as there is no possible way the memory could still be valid after the stack is unwound when the function returns.

If you want the memory to live beyond the scope of the function allocating it, you cannot allocate it on the stack. You have to allocate on the heap via new.

Comment: "C# is protecting you from creating a hanging pointer by not letting you return the pointer" C# is not complaining at all, and the code compiles without problems.

Comment: My apologies. I thought C# had some basic escape analysis to catch cases like this.