# Anonymous delegate not using new local for every iteration when data on local stackalloc

Tags: c#, .net-core, threadpool, anonymous-delegates, stackalloc

When using anonymous `delegate`s in C# the CLR will generate a copy of the local (e.g. variables in the current scope) on the heap for used variables. Such a local will be put onto the heap for every declared variable of the current scope.

You can see this behavior on this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { execute(i); });

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int j = i;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { execute(j); });
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    static void execute(int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" * NUM=" + number.ToString());
    }
}
```

The output of this program is (the order may vary on the last 5 entries while on the first one it's also possible to get lower numbers than 5.):

```
 * NUM=5
 * NUM=5
 * NUM=5
 * NUM=5
 * NUM=5

 * NUM=0
 * NUM=1
 * NUM=2
 * NUM=3
 * NUM=4
```

C# should always generate a new copy of the local when called in a method. This is working as intended in this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            call(i);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    static void call(int number)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { execute(number); });
    }

    static void execute(int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" * NUM=" + number.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 * NUM=0
 * NUM=1
 * NUM=2
 * NUM=3
 * NUM=4
```

**This is the case in question:** However, it's *not* working when assigning the variable to a `stackalloc` reserved area:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            call(i);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    static unsafe void call(int number)
    {
        int* ints = stackalloc int[64];

        ints[32] = number;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { execute(ints[32]); });
    }

    static void execute(int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" * NUM=" + number.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 * NUM=4
 * NUM=4
 * NUM=4
 * NUM=4
 * NUM=4
```

When using a regular local variable - just replace the `call` method from the example above:

```
static void call(int number)
{
    int j = number;

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { execute(j); });
}
```

Output:

```
 * NUM=0
 * NUM=1
 * NUM=2
 * NUM=3
 * NUM=4
```

This situation makes me not trust anonymous `delegate`s in C# - because I don't understand when exactly C# won't fuck up my calls to anonymous `delegate`s.

My Questions: **Why does C# not keep track of the `stackalloc` space regarding anonymous `delegate`s?** I'm aware of C# not keeping track. I want to know *why* it's not keeping track, if it does with a regular variable.

*I used .NET Core 2.1 with C# 7.3 including `/unsafe` switch for those examples.*

Comment: It can't do what you're trying to make it do. As an implementation detail, captures are implemented by allocating space on the heap for their storage. But then you're instructing the compiler that a particular variable should be allocated space on the stack. Based on *current* implementations of lambdas, you're causing a contradiction.

Comment: Added to which, the whole point of lambda capture is that the lambda may outlive the original "scope" in which it's created. But you're then deliberately creating (via `stackalloc`) an object who's lifetime is explicitly tied to the original scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Returning a pointer created with stackalloc inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817754/c-sharp-returning-a-pointer-created-with-stackalloc-inside-a-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're capturing a pointer. That pointer refers to memory that is allocated on the stack by `call` - and the pointer *keeps* a reference to it even after the method has returned, which is fundamentally bad news. You're into undefined territory at that point - there's no guarantee what will be in that memory later.

Each `stackalloc` *does* occur separately - the five pointers you've got are all independent, but they *happen* to refer to the same piece of memory because each is the result of a separate `stackalloc` execution *when the stack pointer is at the same value to start with*. You can still use that memory because it's still valid memory within the process, but it's *not* safe to do so in terms of knowing what's going to be there.

The `ints` variable is "correctly" being copied into a class generated by the compiler, but the *value* of the variable refers to memory which was on the stack at the time of the call to the `call` method. When I ran the code, I got output of "whatever the argument to `Thread.Sleep` was. The C# compiler is capturing the *variables*, which isn't the same as "capturing the entire content of the stack".

You don't need to avoid delegates entirely - you just need to avoid mixing delegates with unsafe code and stack allocation.

You can see this problem without using any anonymous functions at all:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Call(i);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(999);
    }

    static unsafe void Call(int number)
    {
        Helper helper = new Helper();
        int* tmp = stackalloc int[64];
        helper.ints = tmp;
        helper.ints[32] = number;        
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(helper.Method);
    }

    static void Execute(int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" * NUM=" + number.ToString());
    }

    unsafe class Helper
    {
        public int* ints;

        public void Method(object state)            
        {
            Execute(ints[32]);
        }
    }    
}
```

You can see it easily without using *any* delegates, but doing the same thing of "stack allocate some memory, and use a pointer to it after that stack has gone away":

```
using System;

class Program
{
    unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int*[] pointers = new int*[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            pointers[i] = Call(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pointers[i][32]);
        }
    }

    unsafe static int* Call(int number)
    {
        int* ints = stackalloc int[64];
        ints[32] = number;
        return ints;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've raised an [issue on the C# language github](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2182) asking if code like this should at least generate a warning.

Comment: @Matthias: Having run your new code, I don't see how it disagrees with anything I've written.

Comment: @Matthias: I don't understand what you think your pastebin code shows. Yes, you're overwriting some memory on the stack - but then so do other operations, like the call to `Thread.Sleep`. Fundamentally, you're doing unsafe and unpredictable things. *Everything* you've observed can be explained by exactly what I've stated. You really need to accept that capturing a pointer that's been created by stack allocation and then using it later is a fundamentally bad idea.